# XML Transformer weirdly transforms the xml into an empty string on server while it works locally

Tags: java, xml, xslt, transformation

I have the tagging mechanism inside my html , which triggers a java class in my project when the html is rendered. The purpose is to make a transformation of the xml provided as a parameter in the tag and insert the transformed result into the html.

```
<br>Test customTag<br>
<@myWebsite.customTag xmlPath="C:/paths/personalInfo.xml" xsltPath="C:/paths/template.xslt"/>
```

In customTag class, I'm using "javax.xml.transform.Transformer" to transform an "XML" string by an XSLT string. For this purpose, I simply have the following lines ;

```
//Reading the files in the paths given in the url, and converting them into String.
String xmlContent = convertToString(xmlPath); 
String xsltContent = convertToString(xsltPath);
```

Given that their values are as shown in the [following example](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/tryxslt.asp?xmlfile=cdcatalog&xsltfile=cdcatalog_if) ; 
And I have the following code to make the transformation.

```
StringReader readerXML = new StringReader(xmlContent);
StringReader readerXSLT = new StringReader(xsltContent);

TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
StreamSource xslStream = new StreamSource(readerXSLT);
Transformer transformer = null;

StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
StreamSource in = new StreamSource(readerXML);
StreamResult out = new StreamResult(writer);

transformer.transform(in, out);
logger.debug("The generated HTML file is:" + writer.toString());
```

The thing is that it is working in my local application server (Windows), printing what is expected. However when I deploy it into Linux server, the transformation is simply empty .  The only difference that I'm aware of between two servers is that my local is Windows and the remote server is Unix.

And there is no exception or something in Linux server logs. Everything seems to work as it does locally. It is pretty annoying though.

Any idea why "javax.xml.transform.Transformer" does not do its job in this scenario  ?

Edit : Java Vendor is common : IBM's Java lib.

**Local :**
java version "J9VM - R26_Java626_SR8"

**Unix Server**
java version "J9VM - R26_Java626_SR1"

**Log Fragments:**
Local and Server has the same log results for the following lines: 
logger.debug("doTag() xmlContent: " + xmlContent);

logger.debug("doTag() xsltContent: " + xsltContent);

**Only different log** is the result of the following ; prints the new xml in local, but an empty string for the unix.

logger.debug("The generated HTML file is:" + writer.toString());

Comment: One more thing that could differ is Java version and it's vendor. Are you using Oracle Java or OpenJDK on your linux machine?

Comment: Sergey, I edited the question based on your desired details. Thnx.

Comment: Could you also add a log fragment?

Comment: I've made a notePad++ compare check for hundred lines of logs of local and remote server. The only difference is the transformation result.

Comment: javax.xml.transform.Transformer is an interface implemented by many different XSLT processors running on the Java platform.

Comment: There are many things that could cause your code to work on one platform and not on another. Without seeing your code, we can't possibly determine which of these many things is the cause of your problem.

Comment: Michael,  Thanks for the comments.  I tried to provide a bit more details in the question. However, not sure what details more I could give for you to help me. As explained in the question, I have only a tag in my html that triggers a java class in which I simply have the lines of codes provided in the question.    Same java versions , same java project, same XSLT import, but different results.

Comment: Paths of course must be case-sensitively correct, and the file permissions okay (`chmod a+r ...`). **Encoding** could be tricky, UTF-8 can break, but I assume already everythins is UTF-.

Comment: Joop,  I believe there is nothing wrong with the tag format. Because I am able to see the content of the xml & xslt files by logger.debug.   So everything is ok with the paths, and permissions.  Not sure if it is regarding UTF since it is working locally.

Answer (score 0):

Well, all of them made me think about the things that could affect the transformation. 
Because of the reason that transformation is based on xslt being able to make necessary checks  and come out with the result, any thing that could affect the transformation may result in an unexpected result as is in my scenario.

Everything is the same in my local and server but the xslt on the server is somehow fetching some parameters in a different way and looking for those parameters in the xml.  This has been the main reason why the transformation did not throw any exception but returned empty string.
Briefly the following line in the xslt file had no trouble because the parameter pCitizenID had a match in the xml.
The unfortunate difference between the parameters in local and remote server was a letter.  2015-33456AB1-2214 (local) ,   2015-334564B1-2214 (server)

```
 <xsl:for-each select="//sg[page[@pID=$pCitizenID]]/page">
```

So simply , it was all about the way transformation could not work right.  But thanks a lot for the tips & comments that could explain the reasons why some differences could appear between two platforms .   Hopefully no one suffers from the same mistake, but if does, might such discussion help them.